# Sylvester's Determinant identity proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How to prove $$\det(I-AB)=\det(I-BA)$$ if one of the matrices is singular. I tried the following way: Let $A$ be singular. Then $$\det(AB)=0$$ and $$\det(BA)=0$$

Now since $AB$ be singular $\exists$ a non-zero vector $x$ such that $$ABx=0$$  Hence

$$(I-AB)x=x$$  and similarly $\exists$ non-zero vector $y$ such that

$$(I-BA)y=y$$

Any help here?

Comment: I dont think there is a proof for singular matrices in the duplicate

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this identity should hold when $A$ and $B$ are not square matrices, as long as they are of such shapes that $AB$ and $BA$ both exist.

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Dubuque's proofs work for singular matrices, even for non-square matrices.